# Changing the cursor hightlight in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio

VS offers highlighting of matching braces, so for an 'If' block when the cursor is placed next to the opening brace VS will highlight both the opening and the closing brace.

Currently, for the default Blue theme, it's light gray for the highlight.

Is there a setting that help in changing the color of the highlight?

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correct this may help you:

```
Tools -> Options -> Fonts and Colors -> Auto Brace Complete Marker
```

[image]

Comment: @Codehelp: Was my answer helpful for you?